# Plotting multiple responses to MCQs in r

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm currently visualising data from a multiple-choice survey, and have come up against a problem with one of the questions.

Most questions are set up so that participants can only select one answer, however it would seem a mistake has been made with one question, which allowed participants to select multiple answers.

I want to plot this so that the graph still only shows the 6 responses, rather than producing bars combinations of responses as well (as my current code is doing). This is what I have:

```
consultation2 %>% 
  drop_na(q11) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(fill = role.at.university, fct_infreq(q11))) + 
  geom_bar(position = "stack") + 
  theme(
    axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90),
    legend.key.size = unit(0.5, "cm"),
    legend.key.width = unit(0.5, "cm"),
    legend.text = element_text(size = 8),
    legend.title = element_text(size = 10)) + 
  labs(title = "The University should implement the proposed actions relating to \n'Engaging and Empowering our Community'",
       x = NULL,
       y = "Count",
       fill = "Role at University") +
   scale_fill_discrete(labels = c("Student", "Academic Staff", "Professional Services Staff"))
```

This produces the attached graph.

[image: chart]

Could anyone tell me how to present the graph without combination responses, only showing the number of people who selected each answer?

Comment: seems like you forgot to attach the graph, also it would be helpful if you could share a sample data.

Comment: well, it sounds like the first thing you're going to have to do is decide which one of the multiple responses you're going to report.  Then you edit your input dataset accordingly and produce your existing plot, perhaps with a footnote to explain what you've done.  As you've not provided any input data, I don't see how we can advise you more.